# Could not connect to Wi-Fi after editing 'wpa_supplicant.conf' with Python script

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, readwrite

I'm trying a solution that can change or connect to a new Wi-Fi network with a Python script. After executing the code below that changes the content of 'wpa_supplicant.conf', the change of the file works by inspecting the file with `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. But after rebooting the Pi to get it to connect to the new network, the Pi couldn't connect to any networks since then.

```
SSID = input('Enter SSID: ')
password = input("Enter password: ")

with open('/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf', 'w') as file:
    content = \
        "country = MY\n" + \
        "ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev\n" + \
        "network={\n" + \
            '\tssid="' + SSID + '"\n' + \
            '\tpsk="' + password + '"\n' + \
            "\tkey_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" + \
        '}'

    file.write(content)
```

When executing the `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` command line, I got an error of

> wlan0 interface doesn't support scanning network is down

"Network is down" was removed after executing `ifconfig wlan0 up`. But the error still shows "wlan0 interface doesn't support scanning" when I execute `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`.

There are no soft or hard blocks seen for Wireless LAN when executing `rfkill list`.

The only way I could think of solving this issue was to reformat and reinstall Raspbian, but I've spent countless hours setting up the OpenCV environment and other third-party libraries, and I don't want to go through that tedious setup process again. Is there any other way?

Comment: Thought it might be no newline at the end of the file (this can be a thing with some things), but I tested that, not the problem.  **Did you try executing `wpa_supplicant` manually?** It provides feedback that almost certainly would explain the issue.

Comment: I think you can use `journalctl -xe` to check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

It is far from clear what you are trying to do, however if your Question is how to restore wireless networking after corrupting your wpa_supplicant file all you have to do is put a correctly formatted wpa_supplicant file in the boot partition and reboot.

Of course you could just restore from your backup.

Comment: I've already tried that by creating a 'wpa_supplicant.conf' file with my Windows PC, just like the first time when I install Raspbian on the SD card. But it still doesn't work after creating the file and rebooting the Pi.

Comment: Use an editor that doesn't use CR/LF as line terminators. If this doesn't work you have damaged something else. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours on trying to get this issue resolved but ended up no luck. I even tried creating a new 'wpa_supplicant.conf' file on the boot drive of the SD card on my Windows PC but still, my Pi could not connect to any of the Wi-Fi networks. So, I reformatted and reinstalled Raspbian OS on it.

My plan was to connect to a new Wi-Fi network by rewriting the 'wpa_supplicant.conf' file from a Python script, but this method will break the Wi-Fi system. Luckily, I found a solution to do this.

**Solution:** Instead of rewriting 'wpa_supplicant.conf' using `with open('/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf', 'w') as file:`, rewrite the 'interfaces' file from the `/etc/network/interfaces` path.

You will see this initially in the 'interfaces' file:
[image]

Add this code below the `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d` line:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "WIFI NETWORK NAME HERE"
wpa-psk "WIFI NETWORK PASSWORD HERE"
```

Save the 'interfaces' file and open the 'wpa_supplicant.conf' file:
[image]

Add `update_config=1` between the lines of `ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev` and `network={...`. From my observation, this kind of ignores the contents of `network={...` and divert its retrieval of Wi-Fi information to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Save the file and reboot.

Once rebooted, you can rewrite the `/etc/network/interfaces` file by executing a Python script whenever you want to change to a new network (the script must lead to a system reboot at the end to allow the new Wi-Fi changes to take effect). (I don't know whether the 'interfaces' file allows multiple networks to be added into, so far I only tested with one network at a time, since this has already fulfilled my goal.) Here's a Python code sample to change the network information in the 'interfaces' file:

```
import os
import time

SSID = input('Enter SSID: ')
password = input("Enter password: ")

with open('/etc/network/interfaces', 'w') as file:
    content = \
        '# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)\n\n' + \
        '# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd\n' + \
        "# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'\n" + \
        '# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:\n' + \
        'source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d\n' + \
        'auto wlan0\n' + \
        'iface wlan0 inet dhcp\n' + \
        'wpa-ssid "' + SSID + '"\n' + \
        'wpa-psk "' + password + '"\n'

    file.write(content)

print("Write successful. Rebooting now.")
time.sleep(2)
os.system('sudo reboot now')
```

Comment: **DO NOT** do this. You will break dhcpcd and thus many networking tools.

Comment: You are mistaken about the operation of update-config